# Assign a string value to a property of type Enum which has the corresponding string value as an enumerable const C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following enum:

```
public enum PageIdsOptions
    {
        PageID_News = 1,
        PageID_Signup = 2,
        PageID_AffiliateSignup = 3,
        PageID_Cashier = 4,
        PageID_Promotions = 5
    }
```

and the following property:

```
public PageIdsOptions Hint { get; set; }
```

I recieved a string with this value:

```
string hintValue = "PageID_Signup";
```

And I want to assign the value of hintValue to the property Hint:

```
Hint = hintValue;
```

so that Hint will be equal to

```
Hint = PageIdsOptions.PageID_Signup;
```

How can this be done? Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) method, *(this will throw an exception if hintValue contains any invalid value)*

```
Hint = (PageIdsOptions) Enum.Parse(typeof(PageIdsOptions), hintValue);
```

You can also use [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx), *(this will return a boolean if the parsing is successful or not, but no exception will be thrown)*

```
PageIdsOptions Hint;

 if (Enum.TryParse(hintValue, out Hint))
    {
         //Parsed successfully
     }
 else
     {
        // Parsing failed
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try
{
    var value = Enum.Parse(typeof(PageIdsOptions), hintValue);
}
catch(ArgumentException e)
{
   //todo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
if (!Enum.TryParse(hintValue, out Hint))
{
    // throw an exception because hintValue did not parse.
}
```